# Search in mongodb nested arrays

Tags: mongodb

Here i have this database

```
{
    "products": [
        [
            {
                "title": "CS:GO:0",
                "description": "500 x 6MM CARBON STEEL BALL BEARINGS",
                "moreInfo": "SMK.",
                "oldPrice": "269.99",
                "newPrice": "109.99",
                "offPrice": "59%",
                "image": "",
                "z-index": 0,
                "shown": true,
                "type": "product",
                "category": "0",
                "id": "0"
            },
            {
                "title": "Grid autosport",
                "description": "G&P G&P Tokyo Marui M870 Gas Charging...",
                "moreInfo": "",
                "oldPrice": "",
                "newPrice": "129.99",
                "offPrice": "",
                "image": "",
                "z-index": 1,
                "shown": true,
                "type": "product",
                "category": "0",
                "id": "1"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "title": "CS:GO:0",
                "description": "500 x 6MM CARBON STEEL BALL BEARINGS",
                "moreInfo": "SMK.",
                "oldPrice": "269.99",
                "newPrice": "109.99",
                "offPrice": "59%",
                "image": "",
                "z-index": 0,
                "shown": true,
                "type": "product",
                "category": "1",
                "id": "0"
            },
            {
                "title": "Grid autosport",
                "description": "G&P G&P Tokyo Marui M870 Gas Charging...",
                "moreInfo": "",
                "oldPrice": "",
                "newPrice": "129.99",
                "offPrice": "",
                "image": "",
                "z-index": 1,
                "shown": true,
                "type": "product",
                "category": "1",
                "id": "1"
            }
        ].........
```

I use this as a query to get the object i want

```
var query = {
    "products": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "category": '0',
            "id": '0'
        }
    }
};
var secondaryQuery = {
    'products.$': 1
};

collection.find(query, secondaryQuery)
```

The database returns null array [].

Does someone have idea why and how to get the object I want from it?

Comment: Read he documentation. That is what it there for: [positional `$` operator.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/).Clearly states *"Matches **first** array element only"*. Which of course means that **only** your "outer" array element is ever going to be a match.

Comment: First array is based on categories second is the products for the category they are in